# if clause in linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

i have the following LINQ statement, I need to write inside, the if clause, I did the following but obviously its an error,im asking how can I implement something like this in LINQ?

```
var devices = (from c in db.MasterDatas
               join m in db.TurbineDevices on
               c.turbine_id equals m.turbine_ip
               join t in db.v_vpn_gateway_info
               on m.turbine_ip equals t.turbine_id
               where m.turbine_ip == id                  

               select new TurbineDvce
               {
                  if(t.vpn_gateway==m.device_ip)
                      {Comments =vpn_gateway

                           }else

                   Comments = m.comments,
                   Description = m.description,
                   DeviceIP = m.device_ip,
                   DeviceType = m.device_type,
                   FirmwareVersion = m.firmware_version,
                   Model = m.model,
                   Password = m.psw,
                   Phone = m.tel_number,
                   Producer = m.producer,
                   PublicIP = m.public_ip,
                   TurbineId = m.turbine_ip,
                   Username = m.username
               });
```

Comment: In the else do you want to set all the properties or only the comments?

Comment: What *is* the error? I assume you´re missing a `return`-statement within your anonymous method.

Comment: @GiladGreen this clause is only for the comments

Comment: @HimBromBeere my question is how can I put such a condition there

Comment: You could just use [Conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), e.g. `Comments = t.vpn_gateway == m.device_ip ? vpn_gateway : m.comments,`.

Comment: If the if clause of the if statement is reached, what will be the value of `Description`, `DeviceIP`, `DeviceType` etc?

Comment: @KeyurPATEL you made my day,thanks!it works